# Mule Error sending HTTP request SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.cancelled

Tags: api, mule, httprequest

I've created a mule process API that calls a mule system API using an HTTP request, via the mule `<http:request>` tag. The system API in turn processes the request using a database call. The process and system APIs are deployed to cloud hub. I could successfully test the system API locally and from cloud hub. The process API though gives me the following error message.

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request.
Element               : /get:\/terms:api-config/processors/0/getTermsImpl/subprocessors/0 @ msu-test-p-sisinfo:implementation.xml:25 (httpSisInfoTerms)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Error sending HTTP request. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.cancelled(SingleEndpointPool.java:1284)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:185)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:277)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerCancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:389)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.cancel(SafeFutureImpl.java:247)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1352)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1344)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

The error references line 25 in the file implementation.xml of the process API. The contents of the file are listed below. Line 25 is the call to the http:request configurator defined in global.xml.

```
<sub-flow name="getTermsImpl">
    <http:request config-ref="httpRequestConfig-sisinfo" path="api/terms" method="GET" doc:name="httpSisInfoTerms">
    </http:request>
</sub-flow>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be behind a Proxy server, try to set up proxy information on the Proxy tab of the HTTP Request Configuration.

Comment: Will a proxy matter if both APIs are deployed to cloud and APIs in the cloud can talk to the database?

Comment: It feels like you can't talk to the host you specified on your httpRequestConfig or you get a timeout. The exception seems to be just printing the summary of the exception, you could change that to see more by changing it to Exception Detailed with something like exception.getDetailedMessage()